# Did someone forge Representative Elijah Cummings signature on subpoenas?

Tags: united-states, politics

There were claims on social media (e.g. [Oct 18, 2019 tweet](https://mobile.twitter.com/mchkrem/status/1184858718124630019)) that two subpoenas, ostensibly signed by [Representative Elijah Cummings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elijah_Cummings) shortly before his death, had a forged signature.

This story was picked up by sites like [Gateway Pundit](https://www.thegatewaypundit.com/2019/10/elijah-cummings-signed-subpoenas-from-his-death-bed-but-signatures-on-two-subpoenas-dont-match/).

> [image: Comparison of signatures]

Were documents forged with Representative Cummings' signature?

Comment: The signature comes from [this Wikimedia file](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Elijah_Eugene_Cummings_signature.svg), and is taken from a 2013 letter bearing Cummings' signature.

Comment: It does seem clear that they are different.  But even if one or both of them was written by someone other than Cummings himself (and we don't necessarily know which), that doesn't necessarily make it a "forgery".  It could be that Cummings authorized someone else, perhaps a staff member, to sign his name for him if he was unable to do so or simply too busy.  For all I know, this may be common practice among members of Congress.  Of course, there is also the possibility that Cummings did sign both, and simply changed his signature between 2013 and 2019.

Comment: To perhaps forestall some confusion, when searching for "cummings signature subpoena", there is [a CNN article](https://www.cnn.com/2019/10/17/politics/cummings-subpoena/index.html) on two *other* subpoenas, to Matthew Albence and Ken Cuccinelli of the Homeland Security Department, signed by Cummings on October 16, the day before his death.  The subpoena in the tweet is dated October 10 and addressed to John Dowd, demanding testimony from Lev Parnas and Igor Fruman.

Comment: A PDF of the October 10 Parnas-Fruman subpoena letter is posted on house.gov at https://intelligence.house.gov/uploadedfiles/2019-10-09.eec_engel_schiff_to_parnas_fruman_re_subpoena.pdf.

Comment: @NateEldredge When was the subpoena in the tweet processed or served? Because if it was served before Cumming's death that would completely remove any need for a forged signature.

Comment: @DJClayworth: You're wondering whether the subpoenas were backdated?  [Here](https://www.cnn.com/2019/10/10/politics/read-house-democrats-subpoena-giuliani-associates/index.html) is a copy of the subpoenas from CNN, marked as "Last updated October 10". So it seems clear that the documents were made public in some fashion, with that signature, on October 10, when Cummings was still alive.  I thought the allegation was not that the signature was forged after Cummings died, but that it was forged while he was still alive but too ill to do it himself.

Comment: The analysis keeps confusing a letter "g" for a "y". Obviously the researcher should look deeper into this before coming to a conclusion, especially since the answer by @NegativeFriction is the obvious most likely scenario to consider before jumping on the conspiracy bandwagon.

Comment: I will note that people's handwriting changes, and is often different in different situations.  In particular, a signature with the left hand vs right would be expected to exhibit the variations shown.  Cummings was ambidextrous.

Comment: @DanielRHicks: That supposition needs references.

Comment: @Oddthinking - Oops!  I got taken by a Congressional Record page that contained two different stories.  But the fact remains that the two signatures have the hallmarks of right-handed (on the left) and left-handed (on the right).  And the one on the right is "formal", while the one on the left is more "informal".

Comment: And the conspiracy theorists may like to consider that when a person is very sick, their signature might look a little different.

Comment: Several other examples of the signature from the years between 2013 (Wikipedia version) and 2019 (disputed signature) can be found on the net. These signatures, at least to an untrained eye, also show a great deal of variation and may even seem more similar to the allegedly forged signature than to the old 2013 signature found on Wikipedia.

Answer (score 6):

Per some quick googling, it is [legally permissible](https://lawpath.com.au/blog/legal-sign-someone-elses-behalf) to allow a [third party to sign your name for you.](https://www.criminaldefenselawyer.com/resources/if-someone-gives-me-permission-sign-their-name-have-i) There are some specific legal hoops to jump through, but I doubt that a Congressman's staff wouldn't jump through said hoops.

Cummings had longstanding health complications prior to his death, and had been hospitalized before. He'd been diagnosed with cancer since 1994, and had lived with its effects until his death. It is very likely that he allowed a fellow member of his party to sign the bill in his stead, which is completely legal, when he was unable to sign it in person. Given the extremely divided nature of these subpoenas, I think it is reasonable to believe that he would have been comfortable stating that his vote should go with the majority of his party in the event that he had to vote through a proxy.

It's difficult to find a source conclusively stating one way or another, but given the fact that the subpoena aligned with the statements that he made on Capital Hill, I think it's reasonable to conclude that he simply granted the power of signature to someone he trusted while he was hospitalized or otherwise indisposed.

Comment: Your first reference is an Australian site, and its answer is based on Australian law (so doesn't apply here). Your second reference is about signing under procuration (under US law). When someone signs under procuration, they would normally sign their own name and then list the name of the person they are signing for next to that. (see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procuration#Business_usage ) I am not aware of any US law that legally allows one person to sign another persons name as if they were that person.